# Is there a way to mark Facebook posts for later reading?

Tags: facebook

When scanning posts on Facebook, I'm wishing I could "Favorite" or "Star" particular posts so I can review them later. It's easy enough to do this on Twitter or Google Reader, and I'm surprised Facebook doesn't seem to have such a feature.

Is there a way to mark posts for later reading, whether it be direct or some workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is middle-click on the time (e.g. "18 minutes ago") on any post to bring up just that post and its comments in a new tab (depending on your browser and its settings).  Then when you have some time you can go through the tabs you've opened.  Alternatively, if you don't want to keep the tabs open, you could drag the time to a bookmarks bar in your browser or right-click and choose Bookmark This Link (if your browser has this option) to create a regular browser bookmark for the post.

Comment: I hadn't known you could click on the time bit to get the single view of the post. Given that knowledge, that the post can be bookmarked or otherwise stored, I can just send them to Instapaper for later review.

Answer (score 2):

There's a third-party solution that generally works: you can create a "recipe" at IFTTT which adds to Pocket whatever you Share on Facebook timeline. Or simply "Use" this recipe which does exactly that: https://ifttt.com/recipes/98028

If you choose to share everything for "Only me" (and if you don't Share anything else on your timeline on Facebook), it does the trick.

The known issues so far are:

- private posts are titled "Facebook login" in Pocket
- you need to remember to choose "Only me" first time, and every time you choose to share with friends (and the next time you choose to save privately)
- when you "save" a link shared by someone else, their own comments to the link don't appear on Pocket

---

Alternatively and for future, make sure to vote for [Foursquare-Pocket integration promised by Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/foursquare/pocket/).