# How to save Facebook likes to Pocket?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, if-this-then-that, pocket

For Twitter favorites, I am using IFTTT so that every time I favorite something on Twitter, a [new entry is added to my Pocket queue](https://ifttt.com/recipes/112234).

Could the same be achieved for Facebook likes somehow?

Comment: IFTTT currently has no *liked a new post* trigger.

Comment: This solution is not precisely for your question, but you can [add to Pocket whatever you Share on Facebook timeline](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/49130/36316).

Comment: Alternatively and for future, make sure to vote for [Facebook-Pocket integration promised by Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/facebook/pocket/).

Answer (score 1):

Still not currently possible with IFTTT, since there is no "Like" trigger for the [Facebook channel](https://ifttt.com/facebook).

The closest analog you can get (right now) is to capture "link posts" that you create. If you "like" something, post a link to it.

[New link post by you trigger](https://ifttt.com/channels/facebook/triggers/23)

> This Trigger fires every time you create a new link post on Facebook.

You can build a recipe off of this to save your link post to whatever service can take it, like Pocket. (Or, use one that someone else has already built, like [this one](https://ifttt.com/recipes/44506).)